# jQuery $(element) undefined whilst executing .click() method - returns element at all other times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

Have a really strange issue that a colleague was facing which I managed to work around, but for the life of me cannot understand why his initial code did not work! - we have a legacy asp.net web application that is using MasterPages/Content controls and has jQuery mixed all over the web application providing some client interactivity.

Essentially there is a web form view that has a div containing a button which is initially hidden (display: none), upon clicking another menu item, this div is shown using jQuery BLOCKUI Plugin, blocking the rest of the UI and rendering the popup div into place - the user can then click the button, clicking the button should hide the containing div, and show another div that contains another two buttons - all should be simple.... but this is where it got funky:

Bear in mind none of this content is dynamically generated, all HTML elements are present within the .aspx view up front after the page is finished loading.

```
 var blockUiRenderFrame = function (html, width, height) {
        window.parent.$.blockUI({
            message: html,
            css: {
                top: ($(window.parent).height() - height) / 2 + 'px',
                left: ($(window.parent).width() - width) / 2 + 'px',
                width: width
            }
        });
    };

<div id="anotherContentFrame">
    <p>some text</p>
</div>

<div id="contentFrame" style="display:none;">
    <div id="myButtonContainingDiv">
        <button id="aButton" />
    </div>
    <div id="myOtherButtonsContainingDiv"></div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myButton").click(function() { 
        $("#myButtonContainingDiv").hide();
        $("#myOtherButtonsContainingDiv").show();
    });
});

<!-- A Button on the page calls this code -->
blockUiRenderFrame($("#contentFrame"), 200, 200);
```

What I observed occurring was what appears to be a complete loss of context, or executing the event under a different context all together... during the handling of the click event, the div elements, or indeed anything within the HTML div contentFrame all return undefined.

At *any other time* if I use the console/debugger, I can successfully return an element using say $("#myButtonContainingDiv").

The click event has its correct event element, I can use $(this) to get the button I clicked on, but even trying to **select $("#myButton") *within* the actual click event handler code itself** returns 'undefined'.

I *can* access $("anotherContentFrame") perfectly fine, at any time, including during the handling of the click event of #myButton.

The **workaround** I had to use in order to get this code to work was:

During the click event handler, use the following:

```
$(this).closest('div').hide()
$(this).closest('div').next().show()
```

As this was the only way I could get any reference to the DOM elements on the page to successfully hide/show them.

I can try to give out some more information if anyone wishes, I am not sure if anyone has ever seen an issue like this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Weird. Hard to help without seeing it in action. Regardless, you can combine those lines like so: `$(this).closest('div').hide().next().show();`

Comment: I tried to make a fiddle with similar code - but it executed as I would have expected, so didn't add it to here. The only difference being not being able to set up asp master pages and content/etc. It's one of the weirdest issues I have seen but going to assume at this point it is implementation specific, and nothing to do with jQuery - as I tried basic Javascript accessors and they do not work either!

Answer (score 0):

Your event is not firing because jQuery doesn't know the element, because its state changed dynamically. In order to be sure to fire your click event, no matter the context, you can use

`$(document).on('click', '#myElement', function(){});`

By doing that, you are refering to the easiest "non dynamically generated" element, and jQuery will always be able to find your element.

You can then access your element properties with :

```
$(this)
```

Comment: The click element executes fine - my workaround code executes fine, I just don't understand why when inside the click handling code, I cannot simply do $("#myButtonContainingDiv").hide() - because #myButtonContainingDiv returns undefined when _inside_ the click handler - at any time outside of it, the jQuery object is returned as ou would expect.

Comment: You cannot do that because jQuery doesn't know your element at that time, because its state was change dynamically, this is why you have to refer to the closest "non changing dynamically" element, and $(document) is usually the easiest way to do that.

Comment: I think you mis-understand the strange issue I have - It does, that is the puzzling part - I have no problem getting access to $(this) when in the click handler - and both methods of registering the click event work (the document.on propagation, and standard click handling via (element).click(). The issue I am facing is not the Click handler not working - it does work, it is rather I cannot access $("#myButtonContainingDiv") when inside this handler, when it is in the initially rendered HTML, and never changed dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Where's the code showing your button?

When you call `$(element).click()` it will try to bind to your element on the DOM that is already loaded (no async elements!). If you're loading the `#myButton`  via a async call, you need to bind the click on a parent element and then filter the function call to your `#myButton` like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#myButton', function(){});
```

This way you're sure that the element (in this case, document) existing when jQuery tries to bind the click event and it will only fire it when clicking on the filter you specified as the 2nd parameter to the `.on()` call, in this case, your `#myButton` element

Comment: #myButton is statically loaded - that is the weird thing, like I mentioned in the question, I can access that div element at every time _other_ than when inside the click handler.